# LESS css - JS Parser vs Compiled

Tags: css, less

I was wondering if anyone knew if the JS interpreter for LESS css causes any noticeable delays in page loading. I would prefer to use the JS parser simply because it's easier to use, since I won't have to run the compiler after every edit and easier to manage the source code as SCM tools won't be tracking both the .less and .css files

Comment: You don't have to manually compile after each edit. Just let your less files be watched for changes. I use SASS, and all I do is run `sass --watch sass:css` in the command line. Also, doing it with JS supposedly makes the page quite slow on mobile environments...

Comment: You can also have your `.htaccess` file direct referenced `.less` files towards the compiler and return the compiled CSS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12274629/1455709

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its not slow on fast computers/browsers. However depending on your target audience I wouldn't use it.

I would rather setup `lessc` to watch a file/directory and generate css files on save. And then commit both the less and the css files to your SCM (that is infact what I do).

Also doing it this way allows for continuous integration builds.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest parse LESS styles into normal CSS. There're still people who have JS turned OFF or who use some JS-blocking addons. In such case, you'll get unstyled page, which is **not** the best way to impress your audience.

If you're on Mac - try [Less.App](http://incident57.com/less/)
If you're on Windows - try [WinLess](http://winless.org/)
If you're on Linux - try [SimpleLess](http://wearekiss.com/simpless)

All applications have an Option to "watch directory" (with LESS styles) and compile automatically if changed. Less.App & WinLess have a lot of other options like: compile minified, start with system, start minimized, etc...

Comment: People who disable JS can... go away. I mean, why do that. JS is part of the web. Its like disabling all application written in C.